# Manage many to many relations in FosRest Bundle

Tags: rest, symfony, doctrine-orm, fosrestbundle

I am using FosRest Bundle with symfony and I have a many to many relations between two tables.
For example:

```
class Site
{
    /** ManyToMany **/
    protected $languages;
}

class Language
{
    /** ManyToMany **/
    protected $sites;
}
```

I had records previously saved in each table separately but now I want to add relations between them in my new table **site_language** but I am not sure how to do it.

In SiteController I have these methods:

```
getSitesAction()
getSiteAction()
postSiteAction()
putSiteAction()
patchSiteAction()
deleteSiteAction()
```

Should I create a new method like postSiteLanguagesAction()?
Or modify the existing postSiteAction()?

Answer (score 0):

Sort answer: probably both, kinda.

There are two separate concerns here:

- altering the languages, that the site has ... though, I probably would just call it `postLanguagesAction()` instead
- adding new sites

There are are actually two other methods, taht you forgot about: `putSiteAction()` and `patchSiteAction()` (TBH, I am not sure why you support both). When you update the existing site configuration, you will also need to have an ability to update its available language set.

> <sup>**P.S.**
>
>   Regarding names, since you controller is most likely already called "Sites", I would have called the methods `postResourceAction()`, `getResourceAction()`, `getCollectionAction()`, etc., because it is kinda hard to see the difference between "posts" and "post" at a glance. And it would also make the "specialized methods" more noticeable.</sup>